# jQuery ajax call to python

Tags: python, jquery

We are now using an application in which we have a HTML page, WCF service and C# library involved. What we would do in our application is, we make a ajax call from the HTML to the WCF service and based on conditions within WCF service we would call the respective method available in the C# library.
Current Flow:  Jquery(AJAX call from script part of HTML)   WCF Service  C# library and return back the processed information

Now our query is that 
1.  can we use python as end-point instead of WCF service?
2.  can we raise a ajax call to python end-point and from python end point to C# library and return back the processed information to script?
Proposed Flow: Current Flow:  Jquery(AJAX call from script part of HTML)   Python  C# library and return back the processed information.

If this proposed flow is possible kindly provided steps, blog links or sample which would be useful to us as we are beginner in python.

Thanks in advance.